# Why i didnt i get the datatable in the function?

Tags: .net, vb.net

*This has been fixed* I missed out the add parameter in executesqlquery

I have been doing this, however, I don't understand, when I hardcode the companyID in @companyID , I get the  return objProjectDS correct, however, if  I used the parameter I declared, I get nothing, anyone can explain to me? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Function fnLoadProjectCodeList(ByRef intCompanyID As Integer, ByVal intIncSelectLater As Integer) As DataTable

    Dim strProjectLoadSQL As String = ""
    Dim objProjectDS As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim objMyCollect As New Collection()


    Try
        strProjectLoadSQL = "Select Project_id as id,Project_Code, Quote_Code_id from project_code where company_id = @companyID and Deleted_flag='N';"
        Dim objParam1 As New MySqlParameter("@companyID", intCompanyID)
        objMyCollect.Add(objParam1)


objProjectDS =StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnExecuteSQLQuery(strProjectLoadSQL, objMyCollect).Tables(0)

Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return objProjectDS

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe there is an exception being reported?  Your code is eating them and hiding any problem from you.  Get rid of the Try/empty Catch and see if there is an error.

Comment: You're not adding the SqlParameter to the sql cmd object it seems - where is the code for `StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnExecuteSQLQuery()`

Comment: adaam - StringBusinessObject.Web.ClassBusinessObjectMySQL.fnExecuteSQLQuery()  is below the objMyCollect.Add()objParam1

Comment: plutonix -okay.i try that

Comment: hey plutonix - what i get is this {"Cannot find table 0."}, but when i hardcode the company id, i get the table. its funny as if i missed out something which i don't know here.

Comment: hey, i got it..understood what you are saying.:)  thanks adaam

Comment: Please, add your solution as  an answer and accept it